# confusion over simple variable declaration jQuery "$variable" vs javascript "var"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple ghost text implementation:

HTML code:

```
<div id="searchPanel">
     <form method="get" id="searchBox" action="somePage.php">
     <input class="ghText" type="text" name="query" value="search here"/>
     </form>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $txtField = "#searchPanel form input.ghText";
        var value = $($txtField).val();
        $($txtField).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == value)
                $(this).val("").removeClass("ghText");
        });
        $($txtField).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val()==""){
                $(this).val(value).addClass("ghText");
            }
        });
});
```

The example above is not going to work. When the user focuses the cursor on the search bar, the class "ghText" wont be removed for some reason.

However now if I change the "var value" (variable initialization) and "value" with 
"$value" as in:

```
$value = $($txtField).val(); 
$(this).val($value).removeClass("ghText");
$(this).val($value).addClass("ghText");
```

everything works perfectly.

I can just go to sleep and not worried too much about it..but I am very curious why something like that can happen?

is it because of the "this" not referreing to the right object, or is it because i tried storing jQuery object in non-jQuery variable or is it about something else..can somebody point out to me what was wrong? I have always thought that "var x" is the same as "$x"..?

Comment: I ditto-copied your code into a fiddle and it works without having me to change `var value` to `$value`. Probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Salman A: seriously? now thats weird since that code doesnt work. can you link me to the fiddle where you copy-paste my solution?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You seem to be confused about JavaScript variables. There is no such thing as "jQuery variables" and "non-jQuery variables". Some specific cases:

- A variable declared with **var** is different to a variable without. "var x" is a *local* variable, so it will not share a value with other functions which also have a variable called "x". This is almost always a good thing, so you should almost always declare variables with "var".
- The $ in jQuery is sort of special. It isn't *that* special; it's just that jQuery has declared a variable called "$" which does some fancy operations.
- There is nothing special about variables that begin with "$". In other words, "$x" is just a variable name. It is a different variable to "x", and it isn't a "jQuery variable". It's just a JavaScript variable called "$x". (This is different from PHP, where the $ is actually a special variable syntax.)

So you can just call it "value" instead of "$value".

Possibly the fact that you removed the "var" changed things by making it into a global variable.

As for "this", yes, that is a tricky aspect of JavaScript, and might be causing your problem. The value of "this" inside the inner 'focus' and 'blur' functions is likely to be different from the value of "this" outside. I'm not sure exactly what "this" refers to in an event handler, but it will not be the same object. So what you probably want to do is assign "this" to a variable in the outer function, and then refer to that variable on the inside in place of "this".

Comment: jQuery specific: `this` inside an event handler points to the item that fired that event. E.g. you do a `$('.multiple-items').click(function(){ console.log(this); })` will log one of the `.multiple-items` elements which was clicked.

Comment: @mgiuca: you're completely right, i think i mixed up the concept of "to var or not to var" here with some made-up concept of "jQuery variable" that does not exist at all..i know what the problem was now, and it was not because of 'this'. yes i was able to solve it by removing var since "$value" then became a global variable..

Comment: @Salman A Ah, I thought that might be the case. In which case the `this` inside the focus and blurs will be the txtField, not the document. That is actually what you want in this case (since you're asking for the val).

Comment: @mgiuca: wait, but what about the scope chaining resolution? when focus function tries to resolve "value" and it cant be found in its own function, doesn't it have to check if the outer function already defines it? since "var value" is defined in the outer function of 'focus()' should not it then use the value defined in the outer function (the next value in chain)?

Comment: @Benny: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/3XFjQ/6/) seems to work just the way you expect it.

Comment: Indeed, it will. However, "this" is very special and doesn't follow these rules. "this" is always redefined between function calls. If you have some special library like jQuery, it will define it on event handlers to the handling object. When calling methods, it is set to the object the method is part of. In the default case, it seems to set it to `window`.

Comment: @Salman A:I also tried it just now and it worked on the fiddle...so do you guys have any reasoning why that one in the fiddle works and the one in mine doesnt?

Comment: @Benny: totally no idea. It should have worked even if you have a global variable called `value` with a value other than `search here`.

Comment: @Salman A: okay now it works on mine..i really need more sleep. okay i'm gonna mark mgiuca answer as accepted since he cleared out my confusion about variables. i guess the reason why that code works is simply because 'value' variable is always resolved by being assigned the value of local 'var value' variable, which is how it is supposed to work anyway. thx

Answer (score 32):

When storing a jQuery selection in a variable, it's common practice to add a `$` before the variable name like this:

```
var $banner = $('#banner');
```

It's not necessary to include the dollar sign — `var banner = $('#banner')`  would work just as well. However, the dollar sign reminds you that the variable holds a jQuery selection and not just any value like a number or a string.

Answer (score 1):

@mgiuca is entirely right about Javascript variables - the '$' that precedes them is just a naming convention that most use to identify *jQuery objects*. I add this because you say

> because i tried storing jQuery object
>   in non-jQuery variable

but this is wrong. `$txtField` is a string that you are using to select an object. If you want to store the object itself you should do `$txtField = $(#searchPanel form input.ghText)` and then use it thusly `$txtField.val()`.

Having said that your code works fine for me unaltered. I've set up [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p29cC/) which works on Chrome - is this a cut down version of you code?

Comment: @Inrbob: yes i dont know why it worked on fiddle but not on my full app code. i am using chrome as well and so far i cant get it to work on my application..i still have to change the value variable into global in order to make it to work..

Comment: hmm, how big is your code? I personally would be a bit worried if I **had** to use a global variable for a localised function... if your code isn't too big you could post it up OR if you have a accessible dev environment you could give us a url. Up to you :)

Comment: @Inrbob: i found it working on mine just now..(see my comment on the accepted answer). thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

In to addition @mgiuca's answer here is a little more elaborate approach to your problem that also shows some of the jQuery concep:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  // define two helper functions
  var removeDefault = function () {
    if( $(this).val() == $(this).data("defaultValue") ) {
      $(this).val("").removeClass("ghText");
    }
  };
  var setDefault = function () {
    if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
      $(this).val( $(this).data("defaultValue") ).addClass("ghText");
    }
  };
  // the following works on all input elements
  $("#searchPanel form input.ghText").each(function () {
    $(this)
    .data("defaultValue", $(this).val())
    .focus(removeDefault)
    .blur(setDefault);
  });
});
```

Note

- the use of `.data()` to associate a value with a specific element.
- the use of `.each()` to apply the same behavior to any number of elements
- the use function references for `.focus()` and `.blur()` - jQuery will always set the `this` correctly on its own
- see it working over here http://jsfiddle.net/xsXxn/

Answer (score 0):

So $x is a jQuery variable after all :) ... Well, anyway, here is one instance when $ or not $ did make a big difference in my code:

...load("whatever.php", {par1: var1, par2: var2})

didn't work, at least inside the $(obj).attr() assignment, unless $var1, $var2 where used. This worked:

$(obj).attr("onClick",$("#wherever").load("whatever.php", {par1: $var1, par2: $var2})...