# Where 'this' refers to in this sample of jquery code?

Tags: jquery

Here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html it says that "In JavaScript **this** always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of."

However, I'm confused where **this** refers in the code sample below because of the nested anonymous functions.

```
Drupal.behaviors.ajaxPoll = function(context) {
  $('form.ajax-poll:not(.ajax-poll-processed)', context).addClass('ajax-poll-processed').each(function() {
    // Find the form and poll wrapper items that will be affected.
    var $form = $(this);
    var $pollWrapper = $form.parents('.poll_content, .poll').filter(':first');
```

...

Is the object of the function (which is referring to **this**) Drupal.behaviors.ajaxPoll?

Also, I have understood that writing $form is basically the same as writing jQueryform. What is the logic of using a $ -sign in the name of a variable?

Comment: _'In JavaScript `this` always refers to the "owner" of the function we're executing'_ - Except when it doesn't. [MDN's explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is worth a read. The `$` is just another character when it comes to naming a variable.

Comment: $ is just a convention for naming jquery object. Use your console. you will see 'this' refers to the form currently targeted inside the each loop, thx to closure

Comment: it actually *is* the owner of the function we're executing at that very moment. (because of the way jQuery implements .each())

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, `this` is dynamic. Depending on where/how a function is called, it can take different values. This is much unlike most OO language you may know, where you can statically define the value of `this`.

In your example, jQuery documentation for `each` states that `this` will be set to the element currently enumerating. So it should be an HTML form element.

This (no pun intended) is one very confusing aspect of javascript, there is a lot written about it on the internet, which I encourage you to read.

Note that you can fix the value of `this` inside a function to a specific value, no matter the caller, using `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `this` referes to each `form` element, that the selector matched.

But from a technical perspective it entirely depends on how the `each` method is implemented.

jquery's each is implemented using javascripts `apply` method which allows to define manually what `this` refers to inside a method (which is as I said each form element).

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer for sure on the first question, but I can for the second one:

It's just a naming convention to designate JQuery objects nothing special about that, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288649/confusion-over-simple-variable-declaration-jquery-variable-vs-javascript-var), behind it's a Javascript object