# The difference between $("<p></p>") and "<p></p>"

Tags: jquery

I used `var foo` and `var $foo` in my learning examples, but cannot tell the difference between:

```
<p id="css">CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) is a representation style sheet language.</p>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var js = "<p id='js'>JavaScript often abbreviated as JS, is a high-level, interpreted programming language.</p>";
    var $jquery = $("<p id='jquery'>jQuery is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML.</p>");
    $("#css").after(js);
    $("#css").after($jquery);
})
</script>
```

In the above minimal codes, they function identically, when perform insert operations like `$().html, $().before()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288649/confusion-over-simple-variable-declaration-jquery-variable-vs-javascript-var

Comment: Insertion methods can accept valid html strings, dom nodes or jQuery objects representing elements so there is no reason you would see any difference in page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple explanation is `"<p></p>"` is a simple string. `$("<p></p>")` produces an actual DOM object wrapped in a jQuery object. See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

See the console output in the code below:

```js
var js = "<p id='js'>JavaScript often abbreviated as JS, is a high-level, interpreted programming language.</p>";
var $jquery = $("<p id='jquery'>jQuery is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML.</p>");
$("#css").after(js);

console.log(js);
console.log($jquery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check the documentation for [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/). You will see that there are many options for what can be inserted, including an HTML string or element. This is why both work the same in your code.

Note that prepending a variable name with `$` is a convention to denote an object that has been created or retrieved via jQuery. The `$` actually does nothing.

Comment: _"`$("<p></p>")` produces an actual DOM object"_ <- it produces a jQuery object wrapping a DOM object