# returning CSS value for a jQuery UI element

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm not sure if this is possible via jQuery or other approach, but i've incorporated the theme switcher widget into my web app. I have a set of Selectable UI elements that I'd like to color the same as the current theme's ui-state-highlight color upon page load/theme switch. I'm attempting to store the value of the background in a var, so I can use .css to set the selectable color to match.

`input = $('.ui-state-highlight').css('background')`

returns undefined, but if I try with

```
input = $('.ui-state-default').css('color')
```

I can return a value.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example you have no period before `'ui-state-highlight'` so you are trying to select elements with a TYPE of ui-state-highlight (as opposed to a type of DIV, INPUT, SELECT, etc)

```
 $('ui-state-highlight')
```

Your second example you actually select elements with a class of 'ui-state-default'

```
 $('.ui-state-default')
```

**Edit:** Based on your corrections I am guessing that the problem here is that you may be trying to get the background color for any elements with the ui-state-highlight class but there aren't any actually displayed on your page.

Try the following code, based on answer to [Get a CSS value from external style sheet with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707790/get-a-css-value-from-external-style-sheet-with-javascript-jquery)

```
var $p = $("<p class='ui-state-highlight'></p>").hide().appendTo("body"); 
input = $p.css("background"); 
$p.remove();
```

You create a new `<p></p>` temporarily and then grab the background color off it before removing it.

Comment: my mistake, that was a typing fail. I do have the period before my selector, my return is undefined.

Comment: I've updated my answer so let me know if it helps at all now or I will delete it to make sure others correctly see your question as 'unanswered'