# JavaScript to copy all CSS to a DOM-created element, except where defined in external stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, dom, properties, copying

I need to be able to copy all of the CSS properties from an existing HTML element to DOM-defined element, except where CSS properties are already defined in an external stylesheet for the DOM element.

I have an external stylesheet:

```
#MyTargetElmnt { font-weight: bold }
```

This works perfectly for copying the all CSS properties:

```
objSource = document.getElementById('MySourceElmnt');
objCSS = window.getComputedStyle(objSource);
objTarget = document.createElement('div');

for (var i = 0; i < objCSS.length; i++) {
  objTarget.style.setProperty(objCSS[i], objCSS.getPropertyValue(objCSS[i]));
}

objTarget.setProperty('id', 'MyTargetElmnt');
```

...but, if the source element has a style of `font-weight: normal`, that's what will stick.

I think what I need is something like:

```
...
objTarget.setProperty('id', 'MyTargetElmnt');

for (var i = 0; i < objCSS.length; i++) {
  if (!objTarget.style.getPropertyValue(objCSS[i]) && !objTarget.style.hasOwnProperty(objCSS[i])) {
    objTarget.style.setProperty(objCSS[i], objCSS.getPropertyValue(objCSS[i]));
  }
}
```

I'm stuck on what to put inside `if ()`

I dumped the `objTarget.style` object into `console.log` and it does not contain any of the CSS properties defined the stylesheet.  `style.getPropertyValue` is the same and I can't use `getComputedStyle` on the target element for comparison because it will contain all of the computed styles that I *want* to copy from the source element (which will cause it to copy no styles at all).

How do I obtain the CSS properties from the external stylesheet for comparison?

Comment: did you try `typeof objSource.css.property !== 'undefined'` ?

Comment: oops, sorry, I had a typo: in the second code block, that should be `checks if objTarget` not `checks if objSource`.

The problem is that `objTarget.css.property` always returns as the default or empty, even though I've given it an ID or class name that's defined in the stylesheet.

Comment: if you want to check any property is defined in javascript you can use  object.property !== 'undefined'. If you already know what property you are looking for just check that against the undefined and if its undefined then it means that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @QambarRaza: I understand the use of `typeof`, but that won't work in this case because they *are* defined as defaults (usually "").  The problem is determining how to get javascript to obtain style properties from the external stylesheet.

Comment: This seems something similar to what you are doing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707790/get-a-css-value-from-external-style-sheet-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Did you try objSource.css.hasOwnProperty(property)?

Comment: @RickyAYoder: tried it, doesn't work.  Always returns false for each property, even those that are defined in the stylesheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if property cssRules exists in document.styleSheets\[i\] object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226205/how-to-check-if-property-cssrules-exists-in-document-stylesheetsi-object)