# How to check if property cssRules exists in document.styleSheets[i] object?

Tags: javascript, dom

How to check if property cssRules exists in document.styleSheets[i] object?

I have found out that I cannot use

```
if ( sheets[i].hasOwnProperty("cssRules") )
  because .cssRules is inherited property.
```

But when I try to use

```
if( sheets[i].cssRules !== undefined )
```

so in debugger (Firefox 48 Toolbox tool) I got exception: SecurityError.

For this reason the code fails.

```
var cssList = function(node) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    var sheet;
    for (var i in sheets) {
      if( sheets[i].cssRules !== undefined )
        sheet = sheets[i].cssRules;
      else
      if( sheets[i].rules !== undefined )
        sheet = sheets[i].rules;
      else
        continue;

      var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: If you’re getting a security error, then that is probably a cross-domain issue – is the stylesheet in question being loaded from a different domain?

Comment: Not the stylesheet. The script is injected from Firefox webextensions (addon). So the web-page is remote and script is on client side. But the webextensions works like that it pretends to be part of the page. Maybe it is some security policy of the Firefox addons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'cssRules' in sheets[i]` to detect if `sheets[i]` has a `cssRules` property.

However, all stylesheets should have a `cssRules` property, and then you will always get `true`.

Your problem is that the `cssRules` getter throws an error for security reasons.

I think the only way to detect that is with a `try` statement:

```
try {
  var rules = sheets[i].cssRules;
} catch(err) {}
if(rules) // ...
```

Comment: Hey, you are genius. Thanks a lot! The catch ... try works!

Answer (score 0):

`sheet instanceof CSSStyleSheet` or `("cssRules" in sheet)`

> SecurityError

That's possibly a [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) violation, depending on from where you got the node and document objects in question

The [CSSOM](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#cssstylesheet) spec says

> If the origin-clean flag is unset, throw a SecurityError exception.

which is only set if allowed by CORS headers or SOP.

Comment: The code is in Firefox webextensions. It is Content Script injected into web-page (a blog). "cssRules" in sheet also was not working.

Comment: then it's probably a cross-domain `<link>`?