# $('').css('height') is returning computed height, not CSS height in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I defined the height property of an element using CSS. If the computed height is different from the defined height, then $(element).css('height') returns the computed height, not the height that I defined in CSS. I thought that `css()` returns the height defined in CSS.

Here's a fiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/D9rQR/
I expected `css()` to return `100px`, but it's returning `20px`. I'm using Chrome.

How do get the defined height (`100px` in the fiddle) using JQuery/Javascript?

**Edit:** In the example, I set a `max-height` to emulate what happens in browsers that don't support `height` for `select`s. I'm using the following to check if the browser computes the height properly:

```
if($('select').outerHeight()<parseInt($('select').css('height'))){
    // browser doesn't support "height" for "select"s
}
```

However, this doesn't work because `$('select').css('height')` always returns the computed height.

Comment: Actually. `.css()` returns *neither* the specified value nor the computed value, but the *used* value, which in this case is being restricted by `max-height`.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16779702/283863

Comment: The only way to do this is very nastily. I'd try to avoid it at all costs. There are solutions in the link @Derek朕會功夫 posted that will work though.

Comment: You're right. I looked at the solution in Derek's link and I've decided to manually add `data-height` attributes to each element for now. `data-height` contains the same value as defined in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`$('select').height()` is height of select without padding

`$('select').css('height')` is actual height (has padding)

`$('select').css('height')` = `$('select').outerHeight();`

Comment: The op wants the `height` value defined in the CSS rules.

Answer (score -1):

If you add `border:0;` and remove `max-height` you will get the correct height, as height does not get applied on selects unless border is 0, not sure if this also applies to ie.