# Get the default css value for an element with javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried different ways for this problem, but each had problems.

For example, when I use `getComputedStyle`, when I want to get a `background` or `background-color` value, I get the value `null` or `rgb`, which is really annoying. Once I use `element.style`, the css value that is not recorded returns to `null`

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#example"),null).getPropertyValue('background-color'); //return rgb

window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#example"),null).getPropertyValue('background'); //return null

document.querySelector("#example").style.backgroundColor; //If the value is not set, returns empty
```

Comment: May you include a [mcve]? I don't know what styles `#example` has already...

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is a little obscure and confusing. I am an **Iranian**

Comment: Friends actually `#example` is an example

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: Try solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16779702/6618051

Comment: l want to get the _default css value_ of an element!