# Setting html canvas font

Tags: html, fonts, html5-canvas, font-face

I need to use Myriad Pro for all text drawn on my canvas. I am loading the font through CSS like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: MyriadProRegular; src: url('/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf'); }
```

and trying to set it for my canvas like this:

```
this.context.font = "16pt MyriadProRegular";
```

the problem is that the font is not being assigned - all my text gets drawn correctly, but with the wrong font. The assingment does work when I change "MyriadProRegular" to any standard web font though.

I have tried all solutions and suggestions on these two posts:
[HTML 5 canvas font being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349947/html-5-canvas-font-being-ignored), 
[External Font on HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117553/external-font-on-html5-canvas), but none of them have helped, and it doesn't seem that any new answers will come to those old posts.

I know there is no problem with my css or the font itself - my canvas gets created through JS after the user fills out a form and pushes start, and that form uses Myriad Pro just fine.

How can I get the canvas to use my font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to upload your font file to your server. Then with the font declaration, it should work.

Comment: It is uploaded - the font is working fine on the form preceding the canvas

Comment: I put this project aside for a few months and when I came back to it, I found that the file was uploaded but I wasn't calling the proper path in my code.