# javascript Stylesheet reload delay affecting DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

```
function switchTemplate(stylePath){
    var ns = $('<link>', {
            href: stylePath,
            id: 'themeStyle',
            type: 'text/css', 
            rel: 'stylesheet'
        });
    $('#themeStyle').replaceWith(ns);
    resetPops();
    positionElements();
    $('#video-overlay').show();
}
```

The stylesheets are loading properly, and showing after a brief delay, but the positionElements function (which positions #video-overlay over a video element using offset()) does not fire correctly. I'm guessing it doesn't have the new DOM positions yet?

I have positionElements(); tied to window resize as well and when I call that right after switching the stylesheet, everything goes to the right place.

I guess I could build in a timer delay, but that doesn't seem particularly reliable. Is there some other event I can tie the positionElements() function to to make sure it's up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this SO question shows how you can determine if your stylesheet is fully loaded ([SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635814/javascript-capturing-load-event-on-link)).  From that you would move any functions that need to occur after it is loaded into this custom event.