# Detecting when CSS file is completed switch

Tags: javascript, css, load

I have a page that allows users to dynamically change the loaded theme (stylesheet). I have a `themeStyle` `<link>` element that stores the currently loaded stylesheet. I'm switching it like this

```
function switchTemplate(stylePath){
    var ns = $('<link>', {
            href: stylePath,
            id: 'themeStyle',
            type: 'text/css', 
            rel: 'stylesheet'
        });
    $('#themeStyle').replaceWith(ns);
    self._cssIsLoaded(ns.get(0), stylePath);

}
```

and then using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635814/javascript-capturing-load-event-on-link/4710344#4710344) to detect if it's loaded.

It was working sporadically, but I realized it was probably never working because the #themeStyle css will always be loaded, but not necessarily changed.

I added passing the css file path to the _cssIsLoaded function, but it changes before the load is complete, so I don't know what to use to check if it has switched.

The only solution I can think of now is to have a hidden div `stylePath` to it as content: element in every stylesheet, and check if that div's content is the correct stylePath... but that requires changing every stylesheet, the HTML *and* the JS as well as just being somewhat cludgy. Is there any more reasonable way to achieve this?

edit: I've thought of just adding the new styles at the end, but there's possibility that not all the styles will be overridden by the new one. There's a base stylesheet always in place and these particular rules being loaded only affect one part of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on adding an incrementing number after the id of the style tag, when I switch the style, I add the new stylesheet and remove the old one, then check with the new number to see if it has been loaded.

```
function switchTemplate(stylePath){
    var osid = $('[id^="themeStyle-"]');
    var stylenum = osid[0].id.split('-')[1];
    var newstylenum = (Number(stylenum) + 1).toString();
    var ns = $('<link>', {
            href: stylePath,
            id: 'themeStyle-' + newstylenum,
            type: 'text/css', 
            rel: 'stylesheet'
        });
    $("head").append(ns);
    $('#themeStyle-' + stylenum).remove();
    _cssIsLoaded(ns.get(0), stylePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be using JS to change the class on the body element. I would then have 2 sets of css. Each set would have all its selectors prefixed with the class you put on the body element. So something like

```
<link href="theme1.css" /> 
contains:
body.theme1 a { color: #ff000; }

<link href="theme2.css" />
contains:
body.theme2 a { color: #0000ff; }
```

Comment: that's a little more elegant than how I was thinking. I would really like a way that doesn't require me to change all of my CSS files, or load large numbers of CSS files on top of each other, though.  The reason I need the 'load complete' functionality is for js to respond to different locations of certain elements