# How to show a loading image while google font loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using google fonts api. In document.ready i requested the google fonts collection and populate the select list with all available font-families. Now when user select any font from selectlist i just append the link in the document which request the selected font and show the font-preview. But i am trying to show the loading image while the font is loading for preview. My code :

```
    $("#ff").selectmenu({ select: function () {
        var img = $("<img />").attr("src", "/images/load.gif");
        $(".preview").append(img);
        $('body').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" + escape($(this).val()) + "' type='text/css' media='all' />");
        $(".preview").css({ fontFamily: $(this).val() });
        $(img).remove();
    }
    });
```

But the loading image is not showing because may be the link tag is requesting the font asynchronously. How can i show the loading image until the font is fully loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another answer provided by [csuwldcat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299239/csuwldcat) on another post.

[javascript: capturing load event on LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635814/javascript-capturing-load-event-on-link)

> Here's what is, in my opinion, a better solution for this issue that
>   uses the IMG tag and its onerror event. This method will do the job
>   without looping, doing contorted style observance, or loading files in
>   iframes, etc. This solution fires correctly when the file is loads,
>   and right away if the file is already cached (which is ironically
>   better than how most DOM load events handle cached assets). Here's a
>   post on my blog that explains the method - Back Alley Coder post - I
>   just got tired of this not having a legit solution, enjoy!
>
> ```
> var loadCSS = function(url, callback){
> var link = document.createElement('link');
>     link.type = 'text/css';
>     link.rel = 'stylesheet';
>     link.href = url;
>
> document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
>
> var img = document.createElement('img');
>     img.onerror = function(){
>         if(callback) callback(link);
>     }
>     img.src = url;
> ```
>
> }

Please vote up his response, ensuring he gets credit.