# Jquery call function after link HREF call complete

Tags: jquery

I m converting HREF dynamically to load some CSS like this

```
$(data).find("link").each(function () {
   var oldHref = $(this).attr("href");
   $(this).attr("href", "pdfviewer/RenderPreviewStyles?csspath=" + oldHref);
});
```

I want to call another function when HREF call is done, something like

```
$(this).attr("href", "pdfviewer/RenderPreviewStyles?csspath=" + oldHref)
 .success(function(){
    alert("Call other function");
});
```

But it is giving JS error

```
$(...).attr(...).success is not a function
```

Please suggest some way around..

Comment: just call function name, whats the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5371426/1414562 ???

Comment: @Hemal i'm getting js error $(...).attr(...).success is not a function..

Comment: Hemal means you dont need a success() function because here is nothing works like ajax (asyncron). Just call your function after $(this).attr('href', "pdfviewer/RenderPreviewStyles?csspath=" + oldHref); yourFunction();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using procedural functions. Just call the next one inside the each function. You only need to use a "success" function if you are performing some sort of asynchronous work.

```
$(data).find("link").each(function () {
   var oldHref = $(this).attr("href");
   $(this).attr("href", "pdfviewer/RenderPreviewStyles?csspath=" + oldHref);
   alert("Call other function");
});
```

jQuery's `attr` function is not asynchronous. Code execution will not continue until it has finished.

Comment: That's what this does. jQuery's `attr` function is not asynchronous. Code execution only continues after it has finished.

Comment: No way around what? This does exactly what you are asking. The second function will not be called until the HREF is changed.

Comment: It is not about just changing HREF, after HREF changed, a function call goes to Controller/action and want to call other function only when HREF call is done, got it?

Comment: @AnilD Yes, I got it.  I don't know any other way to say this more clearly.  This does exactly what you want. The other function will not be called until the HREF is changed.